# How to install custom font before loading website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, font-face

I’ve some custom fonts like Trade Gothic Oblique.ttf, now I’m using this in our website but it does not install before loading the website for installing this font I’ve used the following code:

@font-face

{

font-family: "TadeGothic" , TradeGothic, TradeGothic LT Std;

```
src: url(../fonts/Trade Gothic LT Std Condensed No. 18.ttf);
src: url(../fonts/Trade Gothic Oblique.ttf);
```

}

But it does not work. Can you tell me what’s wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out FontSquirrel at http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface. They show you how to do it.

Note, though, that it works differently with IE than with other browsers. I believe IE requires TTF and other browsers require OTF as the embedded font standard.

Answer (score 1):

Simply using a `.ttf` file type will not work cross browser. If you take a look at this [blog post by Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/), you might get a better understanding for embedding fonts in your website.

There are also many other websites out there with instructions, and a simple search will give you a lot of information.

Comment: Oh that's strange... for me too now. Not sure what happened there. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

`.eot` is only for IE. For others, you should use `.otf` or `.ttf` files. The following should work:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Font 1';
    src: url('Font1.eot?') format('eot'), url('Font1.ttf') format('truetype');
```

}

another way is like the following:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'Font 1';
    src: url('Font1.eot'); // For IE
}

@font-face{
    font-family:'Font 1';
    src: url('Font1.otf'); // For others
}
```